# Drawing using QImage,QPixmap and QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using following code to draw pixels in Qt

```
#include "mylabel.h"
#include "cmath"
#include "QMouseEvent"
#include "iostream"
MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f):QLabel(parent,f){
    disabled=false;
    centerset=false;
    size_x=600;
    size_y=600;
    this->img =NULL;
    this->pxmap=NULL;

}

MyLabel::MyLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f):QLabel(text,parent,f)
{

}

MyLabel::~MyLabel()
{
    delete(pxmap);
    delete(img);
}

QImage *tempimg;
QPixmap *temppx;

void MyLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev){

    if(disabled){
        return;
    }

    if(centerset==false)
    {
        a=ev->pos().x();
        b=ev->pos().y();
        centerset= true;
        return;
    }

    tempimg = this->img;
    if(tempimg!=NULL)
    {
    clear();
    delete img;
    }


    this->img = new QImage(size_x, size_y, QImage::Format_RGB888);


    int x1,x2,y1,y2;

    int x3=ev->pos().x();
    int y3=ev->pos().y();

    x3=x3-a;
    x3=x3*x3;

    y3=y3-b;
    y3=y3*y3;

    r = x3+y3;
    r=sqrt(r);

    int x=0;
    int y=r;

    int d=(3-2*r);

    while(x<=y)

    {

        if(d<=0)
            d += (4*x+6);
        else
        {
            d = d+4*(x-y)+10;
            y--;
        }

        x++;
        img->setPixel(a+x,b+y,qRgb(0,255,255));
        img->setPixel(a-x,b+y,qRgb(0,255,255));
        img->setPixel(a+x,b-y,qRgb(0,255,255));
        img->setPixel(a-x,b-y,qRgb(0,255,255));
        img->setPixel(a+y,b+x,qRgb(0,255,255));
        img->setPixel(a-y,b+x,qRgb(0,255,255));
        img->setPixel(a+y,b-x,qRgb(0,255,255));
        img->setPixel(a-y,b-x,qRgb(0,255,255));
    }

    this->pxmap = new QPixmap();
    pxmap->convertFromImage(*this->img);
    this->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*img));
}
```

class MyLabel is derived from QLabel. When label is clicked first time 
x coordinate is set to x and y is set to b. 
rest is bresenhams circle drawing code. 
I'm creating object like this.

```
mw->tes1=new MyLabel();
mw->tes1->setMinimumSize(*new QSize(600,600));
mw->tes1->show();
```

this code can be run multiple times during the execution. The problem is
the old pixels are still displayed when the code is run for the second time.

if I remove the lines

```
    if(tempimg!=NULL)
    {
        clear();
        delete img;
    }
```

then the code runs perfectly. Old pixels are not displayed only those pixels are displayed which are drawn by latest function call.
If I dont delete it there will be memory leaks right?
please help me.

Comment: `new` and `delete` is not needed here. `QPixmap` and `QImage` are optimized in such way that you can use them as a value (they use copy on write pattern, so usually shallow copy is created). Nothing else can be said since you didn't provide enough information.

Comment: do you mean I dont have to delete those objects?

Comment: Does your code run from QWidget::paintEvent()?

Comment: no it doesnt. it runs from a mouse click event. same thing happens when I try it with button click

Comment: show more code, more context! Like I've wrote there is no enough data to say what is wrong. And yes you don't have to use pointers for `QImage` and `QPixmap` (so `delete` and `new` can be omitted), all memory magic happens underneath so you don't have worry about that.

Comment: I updated the code.if I dont use pointers after multiple function calls(i.e. mouse clicks in this case) the old pixels which are drawn are displayed. I want to show pixels which are drawn by recent function call only.